# Is it possible to create a Portable class library with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, roslyn

This is a very simple code that generates a dll that can be referenced from a Portable class library, but, it is prone error because when I add any reference it accepts non portable references.
How can I tell for sure that what I'm trying to generate is on the Portable profile?,
Here is the code:

```
using System.IO;
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;

namespace Ros1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(
@"using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{   
    public class A
    {
        public int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
          return a + b;
        }
    }
}");
            var co = new CompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
            var compilation = Compilation.Create("HelloWorld", co)
                                 .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("mscorlib"))
                                 .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);

            using (var file = new FileStream("Sum.dll", FileMode.Create))
            {
                compilation.Emit(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Portable Class Libraries (PCL) as a concept is transparent to the compiler. It's basically a project system and reference assemblies feature only. If you want to create a portable class library that targets, say .NET for Windows Store apps and .NET 4.5, you should compile against the assemblies in this folder:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7
```

Every profile folder has a subdirectory called SupportedFrameworks which indicates which frameworks it supports.

To make the PCL work great in Visual Studio, you should also include the [TargetFrameworkAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.versioning.targetframeworkattribute.aspx). Make sure version and profile are set correctly. For the example above you would need

```
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7", 
                           FrameworkDisplayName=".NET Portable Subset")]
```

I don't think we ship these assemblies outside of Visual Studio, so you will need an installation of Visual Studio 2010 (with the [PCL extension installed](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981)) or Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Thank you Immo, I suppose it applies similarly to, Silverlight, now what if I want to generate the assembly on the client, Is Roslyn going to be possible to compile inside Silverlight?

Comment: In order to compile a PLC you need to have the reference assemblies. Given that reference assemblies either require a targeting pack or Visual Studio to be installed it basically requires a developer machine. So in the general case I'd say the answer is no. Why do you want to compile PCL on the client? It seems if this assembly is only used on the client it could also be platform specific, i.e. you could compile directly against Silverlight.

Comment: Yes, my Out of browser app has already all the dlls needed to compile, including asyc targeting pack or any other. The reason why I need dynamically compiled code is because there are some validation rules that come from server. The current state of the art of Roslyn seems half baked (I'm sure Eric Lippert wants to break my legs) if there is no possibility to compile on the client.

Comment: May be I'm missing something but this is not a limitation of Roslyn. For example, if you want to compile C++ code, you need header files. The lack of header files is hardly a compiler limitation. Reference assemblies serve the same purpose as header files; they tell the compiler what APIs are available. From a compiler's point of view they are in no way different than regular assemblies. Why is compiling against the Silverlight assemblies not an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Paulo's asking whether it is possible to use Roslyn in a Silverlight/portable app. The answer is no, Roslyn currently only works in full trust on desktop CLR. It's certainly something we'd like to enable in future.

Comment: No; I believe he wants to create a portable assembly using Roslyn.